Primevue 4 breaks Jest test config
I updated from PrimeVue 3.53 to PrimeVue 4.1.1
The app runs fine without errors.
But when I run Jest (which worked with 3.53) i am getting an error Cannot find module 'primevue/config' from 'src/setup.ts'  I also tried changing the path to @primevue/core/config.
How to adjust my jest setup file? I am a front-end dev with not much jest experience.

You can start with checking on your side that node_modules/primevue/config/package.json file physically exists. It's supposed to since you can run the app but this needs to be verified. I see no explanation for it, 3.53 and 4.1.1 don't differ in a way that could cause import problem like that, particularly with jest. The problem is not reproducible in general but could be something specific to your setup, e.g. ts version is too old. Please, provide package.json, Jest and TS configs for starters, and also full error message.
